# C# HTML Code Reader

Tags: c#, .net

what i'm trying to do this this.  Simply create a C# windows app that when that when i point it to a website will download the HTML code.  Kind of like when you use IE and you choose view source. Any starting point would be great.

Comment: If you use WebClient or HttpWebRequest as per the answers provided here - then be sure to make sure that the proxy settings are correct.  One way of doing this is to use the app.config System.Net configuration section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the WebClient class?

```
using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string html = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.someurl.com");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.

Answer (score 3):

**You probably want to look into [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(VS.80).aspx) in .NET.**

**[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) may be another class for you to explore.**

It provides an HTTP specific implementation of WebRequest which can be used to download HTML (or any other content, really) using the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper around [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), which already does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: While this is a possible solution, .NET provides very clean methods to perform the task the OP wants to do via WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. You can use it for making requests.
Also take a look on a ready-made solution [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)